# Apple Events from Applescripts

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm planning to make a little applescripts to do some action when iTunes change the song in playing, but i can't found how to put my script to listen for the apple event that should launch iTunes when the track change.

Did anyone knows?
i know you can make a objetive-c application can register whith Apple Events Manager to listen for those events but i just want to something simple, so i wanna to do it with an applescript,

i've look around Apple developers docs but i can't found howto do it, so if anyone can help would be great,

thxs anyway.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes does not issue track change notifications via Apple events, only via NSDistribututedNotifications. If you are on 10.6+, you could always write your listener application using AppleScriptObjC, which may simplify things a little, but you'll have to deal with Cocoa either way.